# Generalized sophomore's dream

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

It is well know that
$$\int_0^1 x^{-x} dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-n}.$$

I'm wondering if there is a way to characterize all the continous functions $f: \mathbb{R}^{+}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\int_0^1 f(x) dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n).$$

**Edited.** Given any function $h:\mathbb{R}^{+}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}h(n)=\ell$, it is not so difficult to define a continous function $g: (0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_0^1 g(x) dx=\ell$ and $g(1)=h(1)$. Now, define $f:\mathbb{R}^{+}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=g(x)$ if $x\in (0,1]$ and $f(x)=h(x)$ if $x>1$. We have that $f$ has the properties we wanted.

So I don't think there is a "nice" characterization of these functions and the new question is: which hypothesis can we add to obtain a "nicer" characterization?

Answer (score 3):

I would doubt it.

Take any continuous $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$ with finite integral on that interval too. Chop off at $x=1$. Let the integral be $I$.

Set $f(2)=I-f(1)$ so that $f(1)+f(2)=I$ and set $f(x)=0, x\ge 3$. On the interval $[1,3]$ join the dots with straight lines to make the function continuous (or with care you can create a smooth curve).

The problem is that the integral is defined over an interval which only contains one point of the sum. The sum is defined at isolated points which can be arbitrarily joined together. You need a lot more control and connection between the two to have any prospect of a useful result.

Comment: Look at my edit.