# The integral and the sum - equal, generalisation of $\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^x} dx = \sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{1}{n^n}$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

$$
\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^x}\, dx  \;\;=\;\; \sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{1}{n^n}
$$
- this equality is well known.

---

are there any other examples of the form
$$
\int_0^{f(1)}f(x)dx\ =\ \sum_{n\ge 1}f(n)
$$
where the sequence $(f(n))$ is decreasing and $\sum f(n)<\infty$?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721476/generalized-sophomores-dream

Comment: Yes, for example $f \equiv 0$. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Take $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{1}{(x+a)^2}$ for some $a>0$ to be determined. The function $f$ is continuous, positive and decreasing in $[0,+\infty)$. Let
$$G(a):=\int_0^{f(1)}f(x)dx=\frac{1}{a(1+a(a+1)^2)}$$
and 
$$H(a):=\sum_{n\ge 1}f(n)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(n+a)^2}.$$
Then $G$ and $H$ are continuous functions for $a>0$. Moreover
$$\lim_{a\to 0^+}(G(a)-H(a))=\lim_{a\to 0^+}G(a)-\frac{\pi^2}{6}=+\infty$$
and $$G(1)-H(1)=\frac{1}{5}-\frac{\pi^2}{6}+1<0.$$
Hence, by the Intermediate Value Theorem, there is a value for $a\in(0,1)$ such that $G(a)=H(a)$. 
It turns out that $a\approx 0.5023641723293$.

P.S. More examples can be found by considering $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{1}{(x+a)^r}$ with $r>1$.